# How can I list the child values of the Books node in a List View?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: https://imgur.com/a/78nGQ2]

Using a Database Referance which points to Books I want to reach all of the child elements of Books and store them in a list view. Doing this so that I may be able to pull the rest of the information from the database.

This is part of the code. I want to add the children of the Books note to the idList.

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        books = ds.getValue(Book.class);
        String book = books.getTitle() + " by " + books.getAuthor();
    list.add(book);
    idList.add(ref.getKey());
    }
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent();
           // intent.setType("image/*");
            //  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: Problem was solved by adding the circled nodes as children nodes which I know how to access. I do not think that this is the optimal solution and am still open to suggestions.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Alright, noted.

Comment: And what is happening when you are using this code? Do you have an error?

Comment: There are no errors. I just want to add the above circled nodes into the idList. Left as it is.
idList.add(ref.getKey());

This just adds the Books node three times into the idList.